Cross product limit with angular singularity
I am trying to verify whether
$$\lim_{\Pi \rightarrow \Omega } \frac{(\Omega \times \Pi ) \times \Pi \cdot v}{  \|\Pi \times \Omega\|^2} $$
remains bounded. $v$ is a constant vector, I managed to get to show this is smaller than
$$ \leq \lim_{\Pi \rightarrow \Omega } \frac{\| v\| |\sin \varphi(\Omega \times \Pi, \Pi) |}{ \|\Omega\| |\sin \varphi(\Pi, \Omega)|}$$
where $\varphi(a,b)$ denotes the angle between vectors $a,b$. Unfortunately the denominator is singular as $\sin(\varphi(\Omega, \Omega)) = \sin(0) = 0$ in the denominator and the numerator is indeterminate, as it makes no sense to define the angle between $\Omega \times \Omega = 0$ and $\Omega$. My second attempt was to expand everything down to the basic components, which is equal to
$$\lim_{\Pi \rightarrow \Omega} \frac{\|v\|}{\|\Omega||} \frac{\Big( \cos(\varphi(\Pi, v))\cos(\varphi(\Omega, \Pi))  - \cos(\varphi(\Omega, v))  \Big)}{|\sin(\varphi(\Pi, \Omega))|^2}$$
We now have a slightly less bad $0/0$ singularity in the limit. Differentiating this, (I only study the angle part since the $\|v\|/\|\Omega\|$ factor will not determine the limit existing), I get
$$\lim_{\Pi \rightarrow \Omega} \Big( -\sin(\varphi(\Pi, v)) \varphi^\prime(\Pi, v) \cos(\varphi(\Pi, \Omega)) - \cos(\varphi(\Pi,v)) \sin(\varphi(\Omega, \Pi))\varphi^\prime(\Pi, \Omega)  + \sin(\varphi(\Omega, v)) \varphi^\prime(\Omega, v) \Big) \Big( 2\sin(\varphi(\Pi, \Omega)) \cos(\varphi(\Pi, \Omega)) \varphi^\prime(\Pi, \Omega)  \Big)^{-1} $$
Note I did not specify any angle derivatives, as whatever they are when $\Pi = \Omega$ the numerator equals $-\sin(\varphi(\Omega, v) \varphi^\prime(\Omega, v) + \sin(\varphi(\Omega, v))\varphi^\prime(\Omega, v) = 0$. The denominator equals $0$ again due to $\sin(0)$.
I suspect this is going to keep happening if I keep applying L'Hopital's rule. Are there any other ways to study this stubborn limit?

I don't think the statement is true.
Take $\Pi = \Omega + \lambda u$ and let $\lambda$ go to $0$. You have
\begin{align}
\frac{(\Omega \times \Pi ) \times \Pi \cdot v}{\|\Pi \times \Omega\|^2} 
  &= \frac{[\Omega \times (\Omega + \lambda u) ] \times (\Omega + \lambda u) \cdot v}{\|(\Omega + \lambda u) \times \Omega\|^2} \\
  &= \frac{[\Omega \times \lambda u ] \times (\Omega + \lambda u) \cdot v}{\|\lambda u \times \Omega\|^2} \\
  &= \frac{[\Omega \times \lambda u ] \times \Omega \cdot v}{\|\lambda u \times \Omega\|^2} + \frac{[\Omega \times \lambda u ] \times \lambda u \cdot v}{\|\lambda u \times \Omega\|^2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\frac{[\Omega \times u ] \times \Omega \cdot v}{\|u \times \Omega\|^2}\right) + \left(\frac{[\Omega \times u ] \times u \cdot v}{\|u \times \Omega\|^2}\right) \\
\end{align}
and when $\lambda$ goes to zero it is not bounded.

Very efficient solution. +1
